# Android detect smartphones using Bluetooth

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm working on an Android app which is required to detect the number of smarthphones close to the device the app is running on. For this purpose, I have a working implementation of scheduled Bluetooth BLE scans. I'm detecting BLE devices in the vicinity without issues, but can't seem to find any smartphones in the scan results.

My question is: Can we detect other smartphones using a BLE scan on Android? (Specifically; if we have no control over settings in the other smartphones).

---

I have tried scanning for BLE devices with the following bluetooth libraries:

- [RxAndroidBle](https://github.com/Polidea/RxAndroidBle)
- [Blueteeth](https://github.com/RobotPajamas/Blueteeth)
- custom implementation

To try and detect a smartphone I have tried the following:

- Try to find the bluetooth (mac) address or device name in the scan results for a specific secondary Android / iOS device which has Bluetooth enabled. This includes having open the Bluetooth settings on the secondary device as this is how pairing from smartphone to smarthphone works.
- Check the scan results' (major) device class by comparing the bluetooth device class with [the smarthphone device class](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothClass.Device#PHONE_SMART) or [the major-class phone](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothClass.Device.Major.html#PHONE).

Tested with devices:

- Motorola G3 - Marshmallow
- Motorla G6 plus - Oreo
- Samsung Galaxy S4 - Kitkat
- Samsung Galaxy S6 - Marshmallow
- Huawei P8 lite - Nougat

Other: Bluetooth, bluetooth_admin and access_fine_location (runtime-) permissions are all taken care of.

I can not seem to detect the expected mac address of the devices I have tested with, nor any device which has a 'phone-type' device class. The only device class I run into occasionally is 7936 (1F00), also know as 'uncategorized'. Otherwise it is 0. Any suggestions or information regarding this issue is welcome.

Comment: take note that for security reasons, mac addresses exposed via bluetooth are random

Comment: _"Can we detect other smartphones using a BLE scan on Android?"_ They will need to be programmatically set into the "advertising mode". _"(Specifically; if we have no control over settings in the other smartphones)."_ In that case, no.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With BLE and Classic Bluetooth, Android will discover nearby unpaired bluetooth devices that are currently "discoverable". The trouble is even when the nearby devices have bluetooth enabled, they are not actually "discoverable" until they are on their [Bluetooth Setting page](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/1090201).

So in your case, it seems unlikely that you can detect unpaired devices near the device.